# EF6 - which file based database

Tags: database, sqlite, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

I have a following question. I am developing an application for a corporate customer where some data (a kind of a validation rule engine) would need to be stored. In phase 1, the data were not stored, but created as POCOs, so I have a hierarchical structure of subclasses. As a part of phase 2 (now), the customer would need to edit the rules locally, so they need to be dynamically stored. That should be a local file based database using EF6. In phase 3, the customer would provide a central DB server with either MS SQL Server or Oracle, which would replace the local DB.

The question is - which file based DB can I use? I considered SQLite, but it seems it can not be autofilled with the POCOs "Model first" way, or at least I have myriads of exceptions, missing tables, etc....

Comment: I would skip phase 2 altogether. Does it matter where the database is hosted? A private database can also be hosted on another machine and you'l be ready for the real thing.

Comment: Not possible due to extreme long times involved to even get permission for installation of some software outside development machine. Customer is in top 100 largest companies worldwide, and bureaucracy unluckily also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Server Compact, or SQL Server Express. SQL Server Express requires admin access to install as a service, SQL Server Compact does not.

Comment: Thanks! SQL Server Compact is probably the one I will try. I actually managed to get the SQLite nearly working (NuGet SQLite package specially for Code First was not installed...), but latest on Phase 3 I will need SQL Server family software, as SQLite needs some different code.

Comment: Great! Look at my blog for advice on how to do "xcopy" deployment of SQL CE.